# Mambo Jquery plugin not working

Tags: jquery, plugins

I have been trying to use Mambo jquery plugin refer : http://www.valeriobarrila.com/mambo.html

I guess i followed the tutorial fine, but i am not able to see the canvas ,please help. Let me know if i am not clear, thanks.

PS: the jquery.mambo.min.js is on my local.

```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mambo.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(".demo-label").mambo({
          percentage: 37,
          label: "Lbl",
          displayValue: false,
          circleColor: '#C9D94E',
          circleBorder: '#535920',
          ringColor: "#8E9937"
        });
    </script>

<body>
    <div>
        <canvas class="demo-label" width="180" height="180">
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the script after body tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the script in the page head you need to use the jQuery.ready() callback to wait until the dom is completely loaded, eg:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $(".demo-label").mambo({
      percentage: 37,
      label: "Lbl",
      displayValue: false,
      circleColor: '#C9D94E',
      circleBorder: '#535920',
      ringColor: "#8E9937"
    });
});
```

Otherwise you can include the script as the last element of the body, eg:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mambo.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <canvas class="demo-label" width="180" height="180">
    </div>
    <script>
        $(".demo-label").mambo({
          percentage: 37,
          label: "Lbl",
          displayValue: false,
          circleColor: '#C9D94E',
          circleBorder: '#535920',
          ringColor: "#8E9937"
        });
    </script>
</body>
```